# Is there sparse array implementation in .NET library?

Tags: .net, data-structures

Is there already implemented data structure in .NET library acting like sparse array (where most indexes are empty) with O(1) access by index and O(1) access to next (and previous) element?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756329/best-way-to-store-a-sparse-matrix-in-net.  Or you can try Math.Net: http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of years ago I implemented a sparse collection based on my ["AList" concept](http://core.loyc.net/collections/alists-part1.html). It's called [SparseAList](http://core.loyc.net/collections/alists-part3.html), and it's probably better than any "simple" solution that you might roll yourself. For example, @NathanPhilips' solution has `Insert` and `RemoveAt` methods that call `ToDictionary`. [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is an O(N) method - it regenerates the whole dictionary "from scratch" - so it's not efficient.

[SparseAList](http://ecsharp.net/doc/code/classLoyc_1_1Collections_1_1SparseAList.html), by contrast, is based on the [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree), so it has efficient O(log N) insertions, lookups and removals, and it also uses memory efficiently. It is included in Loyc.Collections.dll in [LoycCore](http://loyc.net/doc/code/classLoyc_1_1Collections_1_1SparseAList_3_01T_01_4.html), available on NuGet (search for Loyc.Collections).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any built-in containers like you want, but as a workaround you can use a `Dictionary` of the following items:

```
class Entry<T>
{
    int previdx, nextidx;
    T data;
}
```

(dictionary in .NET has O(1) lookup, as it's hashtable-based). For the insertion to be O(log n), we need to keep a sorted list of already existing indices (this doesn't exist out-of-the-box, but [can be easily emulated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450856/276994))

Comment: Nice, but I believe not that easy to implement. Well, I guess in my case I will just use linked list of nodes storing its index, insert sort and simple array (or dictionary) lookup. O(n) insertion is bugging me a bit, but I don't think there can be done something about it, neither is it that bad after all.

Comment: @mrpyo: I've just realized that for fast insertion we need a sorted list of indices, so that you can check at O(log n) time which index is going to be next/prev of the new index.

Answer (score 2):

I put together a [list of the lists in dotnet](http://www.selfelected.com/list-of-list-and-collection-classes-in-dotnet-11-45/) a while ago.  There is no sparse list there.
I mention it anyway because it can be some aid if you decide on developing one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sparse array based on a Dictionary (mostly untested, I just put it together after reading this question):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace NobleTech.Products.Library.Linq
{
    public class SparseList<T> : IList<T>
    {
        private T defaultValue;
        private Dictionary<int, T> dict;
        private IEqualityComparer<T> comparer;

        public SparseList(T DefaultValue = default(T))
            : this(DefaultValue, EqualityComparer<T>.Default)
        {
        }

        public SparseList(IEqualityComparer<T> Comparer)
            : this(default(T), Comparer)
        {
        }

        public SparseList(T DefaultValue, IEqualityComparer<T> Comparer)
        {
            defaultValue = DefaultValue;
            dict = new Dictionary<int, T>();
            comparer = Comparer;
        }

        public int IndexOf(T item)
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(item, defaultValue))
                return LinqUtils.Generate().First(i => !dict.ContainsKey(i));
            return dict.Where(kvp => comparer.Equals(item, kvp.Value))
                .Select(kvp => (int?)kvp.Key).FirstOrDefault() ?? -1;
        }

        public void Insert(int index, T item)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", index, "index must be non-negative");
            if (index < Count)
                dict = dict.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key < index ? kvp.Key : kvp.Key + 1, kvp => kvp.Value);
            this[index] = item;
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", index, "index must be non-negative");
            dict.Remove(index);
            if (index < Count)
                dict = dict.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key < index ? kvp.Key : kvp.Key - 1, kvp => kvp.Value);
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (index < 0)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", index, "index must be non-negative");
                if (dict.ContainsKey(index))
                    return dict[index];
                return defaultValue;
            }
            set
            {
                if (index < 0)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", index, "index must be non-negative");
                dict[index] = value;
            }
        }

        public void Add(T item) { this[Count] = item; }

        public void Clear() { dict.Clear(); }

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            return comparer.Equals(item, defaultValue) || dict.Values.Contains(item, comparer);
        }

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            if (array == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
            if (arrayIndex < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("arrayIndex", arrayIndex, "arrayIndex must be non-negative");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - arrayIndex; ++i)
                array[arrayIndex + i] = this[i];
        }

        public int Count { get { return (dict.Keys.Max(i => (int?)i) ?? -1) + 1; } }

        public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

        public bool Remove(T item)
        {
            int index = IndexOf(item);
            if (index < 0)
                return false;
            RemoveAt(index);
            return true;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return LinqUtils.Generate(i => this[i]).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
    }
}
```

The implementation of `LinqUtils.Generate` is left as an exercise for the reader :-)